# IntelliJ IDEA: simple way to create type-safe builder without plugins?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA, I want to create a POJO class that helps me avoid making silly mistakes, in terms of getting parameters around the wrong way.

- I don't care about other IDEs
- I don't want to use any form of reflection (i.e. no Lombok or similar)
- I don't care about the JavaBean standard
- I don't care about "best practices"

I just want to create a class, declare some fields and have a convenient way to create said class that reduces the likelihood that I will get same-type parameters the wrong way round when I create the class.

Starting with this:

```
public class TestObject {
  public String x;
  public String y; 
}
```

I want to generate something I can use, like this:

```
TestObject o = new TestObject().setX("x").setY("y");
```

or this:

```
TestObject o = TestObjectBuilder.withX("x").withY("y").build();
```

I don't mind if there's a separate builder class (prefer to jam all the methods on the original class, but no biggie).

I don't mind if it makes many copies along the way.  Prefer if the whole process creates only 1 instance, like my solution below; but if the solution takes an immutable instance-per-setter-field approach - no biggie.

---

Here's what I currently do to achieve this goal.

**(1)** Use IDEA to `Generate constructor`, selecting all fields, resulting in this:

```
public class TestObject {
  public String x;
  public String y;

  public TestObject(String x, String y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

**(2)** `Refactor Constructor with Builder`, having to select `Use existing`, then copy/paste the `TestObject` name into the field, because why not, resulting in:

```
public class TestObject {
  public String x;
  public String y;

  public TestObject(String x, String y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public TestObject setX(String x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this;
  }

  public TestObject setY(String y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
  }

  public TestObject createTestObject() {
    return new TestObject(x, y);
  }
}
```

**(3)** Manually delete the constructor (because its presence denies use of the default ctor) and delete the createTestObject() method (because it's superfluous, Java gives me a clone method for free).  Leaving me with this little beauty, which is all I wanted in the first place:

```
public class TestObject {
  public String x;
  public String y;

  public TestObject setX(String x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this;
  }

  public TestObject setY(String y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
  }
}
```

How about it, Obi-wan Stack-overflow, is there a way to do this with less pfaffing about?

Another thing I'd like to be able to do is add fields with less pfaffing about.  At the moment, when I add a field I'm doing `generate setter` the modifying the result by hand to be in line with the other setters - is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You are looking for the Builder pattern.

Comment: @Stultuske - yes, but how to use IDEA to generate that code for me automatically, preferrably without plugins?

Comment: Look into auto value from google.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - that's a pretty interesting approach.  I prefer the answer from amseager, but still interesting.

Comment: I believe that the "generate additional code" automatically is the responsibility of the compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I would rather read that code than guess what a compiler plugin is going to generate.  That said, if I was generating enough classes like this, I reckon I would go with the auto-value approach, but only if it was a significant portion of the code I was writing.

Comment: It is always a question of trust.  Note that however that the generated source is actually a normal part of your project so you can navigate to it, debug it etc.  This is in contrast to a byte manipulation framework like lombok which is distilled magic.  IDE-generated code can be outdated - will toString() be up to date if a new field is added for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1. Press Alt-Insert (or "Code" -> "Generate") to open "Generate" menu
2. Select Setter.
3. In the next window select "Builder" in the top drop-down menu called "Template" (by default it's "intellij Default" there).

You'll achieve exactly the same result that you want.

Comment: ZOMG - exactly what I wanted, thank you (can't accept yet, but I will).